# Django run def index(reuqest) in other def without duplication of code

Tags: django, view

in my view.py I have a def index(request): and def other(request):

In def other(request): I want to run the exact same code like def index(request): if request.method == 'POST': and else do something different

Copy the code from def index(request): to def other(request): after if request.method == 'POST': works but duplicate code is bad. If I do index(request) after the if statement, def other(request): return nothing.

What is the right method to achieve this?

```
@login_required
def other(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # do the same like in def index(request):
        index(request)
    else:
        # do somthing different
        pass
    return render(request, 'search/index.html')


@login_required
def index(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SearchForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            # do something
            pass
    return render(request, 'search/index.html')
```

Comment: Can you show us the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can redirect to index function using redirect function.
let your url.py file contains something like

```
url(r'^index/$', 'app.views.index', name='index'),
```

then you can redirect your other view to index like

```
from django.http import HttpResponse 
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from django.urls import reverse

def index(request, *args, **kwargs):
    # your index code
    return HttpResponse(result)


def other(request, *args, **kwargs):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        return redirect(reverse('index', args=args, kwargs=kwargs))
    else:
        # else code for GET, PUT,...
```

if you don't want to redirect, follow the code below

```
def index(request, *args, **kwargs):
    # your index code
    return HttpResponse(result)


def other(request, *args, **kwargs):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        return index(request, *args, **kwargs)
    else:
        # else code for GET, PUT,...
```

Comment: ty, i forgot the return :)